# Is it possible for Tkinter to open update an existing excel template?

Tags: python, tkinter, win32com

Is it possible for Tkinter to open and update an existing excel template ?

Comment: Tkinter can do just about anything that python can ... And since I think that there are python libraries to update excel stuff, then it can probably be done.  The question is how much work are you wanting to put in to making this happen?  If you're asking for something canned that will just do it for you, I doubt that you'll find it.  You could also just have tkinter select the file and then open it in excel for the user... That should be easy, but maybe not all that useful...

Comment: I'm working on a tool that collects data from machine and saves it to excel sheet in a specific cells; hence being reflected on excel graphs .. so I need to update the same excel template fixed and only variables comes from the tool. @mgilson

Comment: You could make a tkinter GUI interface, and use openpyxl to handle updating the excel files. I literally just did this a few hours ago. It's possible

Comment: I'll do so.. Thanks alot @Slayer